# Which order sounds the more natural between「私は最近…」 and 「最近私は…」?

Tags: word-choice, nuances, time

When giving news to Japanese friends, I always wonder if I should write「私は[最近]{さいきん}こういう仕事をしています」 or 「[最近]{さいきん}、私はこういう仕事をしています」.

Is there a recommended order for temporal markers like [現在]{げんざい} or [最近]{さいきん}? If both of them work, is there a different nuance to each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are fine and the difference is small. When you pull out 最近 at the beginning of the sentence like this, it sounds you are emphasizing (or "topicalizing") it. Also in English, you can start a sentence with an adverbial expression (e.g., "Today, ...", "Recently, ..." or "In this lesson, ..."), and it basically has the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can think it like “recently i got my pocket money” and “i got my pocket money recently” :). 
Both are fine in anyways, it’s just matter where you want to put it